Simple raycast hit object detection
I found article at https://maierfelix.github.io/2020-01-13-webgpu-ray-tracing/
It is very interest theme.
Is there any way to implement simple raycast hit object detection in my small custom webgpu lib?
For example :
app.device.createRayTracingAccelerationContainer

OUTPUT: 
UNDEFINED

No help
        this.device = await this.adapter.requestDevice({
            extensions: ["ray_tracing"]
        });

Also undefined :
WebGPUWindow

Is this means that i dont have support for ray-tracing?
 const valueIterator = this.adapter.features.values();
  for (const value of valueIterator) {
    console.log(value);
  }
VM486:3 indirect-first-instance
VM486:3 depth32float-stencil8
VM486:3 depth-clip-control
VM486:3 timestamp-query
VM486:3 float32-filterable
VM486:3 texture-compression-bc
VM486:3 rg11b10ufloat-renderable
VM486:3 bgra8unorm-storage


The linked article suggests that this work was done solely on a fork of Chromium.  It also appears that work on this stalled quite some time back.
